# How Do I Display a Contact's Profile in a Joomla Module Position and also a standard page display?

Tags: profile, joomla, contact-view

I am looking to find out how to display a single contact profile with their name, address and other fields in Joomla please. I have Googled, looked at the Civi CRM docs, looked at search criterias, i've been into the profile display administration and I just can't find a way of grabbing the contact by name and then setting this to a Joomla menu link.

I may also need to display it in a Gantry module position too so info on how to do it this way would be extremely helpful too.

Thanks incredibly!